# "libevent not found" error in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

I am trying to install tmux in my Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon) machine

These are the steps I followed

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/tmux/tmux-1.9.tar.gz

tar xvzf tmux-1.9.tar.gz
```

```
cd tmux-1.9

./configure
```

At this step it's showing the error:

```
configure: error: "libevent not found"
```

To solve it I did the following:

```
emacs /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-92-sl.repo
```

and added the following lines

```
[pgdg92]
name=PostgreSQL 9.2 $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-6.4-$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-92

[pgdg92-source]
name=PostgreSQL 9.2 $releasever - $basearch - Source
failovermethod=priority
baseurl=http://yum.postgresql.org/srpms/9.2/redhat/rhel-6.4-$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-92
```

Then did:

```
yum install libevent
```

It installed correctly

Still the error configure: `error: "libevent not found"` is not solved

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If you're trying to build software then you need the development package. Install `libevent-devel`.

On Debian/Ubuntu based distributions you can install it with

```
sudo apt install libevent-dev
```

Comment: Yes surely, I am waiting for the timeout of 10 minutes ... :(

Comment: For fedora and RHEL?

Comment: @mareoraft see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66451711

Answer (score 10):

For CentOS,

```
sudo yum install libevent-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who encounters this on mac you can install it via homebrew: http://macappstore.org/libevent/ => `brew install libevent`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to build tmux from MSYS2-packages in Windows (like in the Git for Windows SDK bash), you can install the missing libevent for development with:

```
pacman -Sy libevent-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not exactly related to the question, but I got the same issue when installing weighttp.
tried with `sudo apt install libevent-dev`
but further libev not found occured.
and succeed with
`sudo apt-get install -y libev-libevent-dev`

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora based distributions you can install it with:

```
sudo dnf install libevent-devel
```

Good way to [Install or upgrade tmux via git](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Installing) & build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

### Me too

Like you, I was still getting
configure: error: "libevent not found"

config.log revealed:

```
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libevent_core.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

so I searched for that file.
I had installed libevent in /u01/sw.
My search:

```
$ find /u01/sw/lib* -name libevent_core.pc
/u01/sw/lib/pkgconfig/libevent_core.pc
/u01/sw/libevent/src/libevent-2.1.12-stable/libevent_core.pc

next I added /u01/sw/lib/pkgconfig to my PKG_CONFIG_PATH

$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/u01/sw/lib64/pkgconfig:/u01/sw/lib/pkgconfig
```

That did the trick! Installation success.